# Retrieve the last value from array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array name `arrayname` and have some values in below image.

[image]

How can I Get the last value in array `arrayname` even if the value at `arrayname1[7]` is empty. This should ignore empty values and gives the end answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Filter out the empty values, take the last value:

```
$array = array_filter($arrayname1);
$lastValue = end($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

**BENCHMARK:**

I redid the benchmark on my own server, as CodePad was giving sporadic results from it's sporadic server load, and it uses an old version of PHP.

Results:

```
(Target: 100003)
Last Value: 100003
array_filter took 8.4615960121155 seconds
Last Value: 100003
array_flip took 20.312706947327 seconds
Last Value: 100003
array_pop took 6.7329788208008 seconds
```

The benchmark script is:

```
$array=array();
for($run=0; $run<100000; $run++)
{
$rand=rand(0,4);
if ($rand===0) $array[]=''; else $array[]=(string)$rand+$run;
}
$save=$array;

echo '(Target: '.end($array).")\n";
$time=microtime(true);

for($run=0; $run<1000; $run++)
{
$array=$save;
$array = array_filter($array);
$lastValue = end($array);
}

$time=microtime(true)-$time;
echo "Last Value: $lastValue\n";
echo "array_filter took $time seconds\n";
unset($array_2);
$time=microtime(true);

for($run=0; $run<1000; $run++)
{
$array=$save;
$array = array_flip($array);
unset($array['']);
$lastValue = array_pop(array_flip($array));
}

$time=microtime(true)-$time;
echo "Last Value: $lastValue\n";
echo "array_flip took $time seconds\n";
unset($array_2);
$time=microtime(true);

for($run=0; $run<1000; $run++)
{
$array=$save;
$lastValue = array_pop($array);
while($lastValue==='')
 {
 $lastValue = array_pop($array);
 }
}

$time=microtime(true)-$time;
echo "Last Value: $lastValue\n";
echo "array_pop took $time seconds\n";
```

The winner is:

```
function array_last_noempty($array)
{
$lastValue = array_pop($array);
while($lastValue==='')
 {
 $lastValue = array_pop($array);
 }
return $lastValue;
}
```

Comment: Somewhere behind the scenes it's still iterating through each value... I'd like to see a fair benchmark to prove that this really is faster, even with the overhead of calling two-and-a-half functions instead of one. I'll admit the possibility though. :)

Comment: Interesting and cool.. `array_flip` method took less time.. excellent work @Alasdair

Answer (score 1):

There is no-way to find the empty values that you needed, but there's an another way to create another array and find the end value.

Below is a sample example

```
<?php
    $fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry','', 'fadsf', '', '');
    echo "Count : " . count($fruits);

    $k = count($fruits) - 1;
    foreach($fruits as $pos => $v1) {
        if($v1 != "") {
            echo "$v1 <br>";
            $newarray1[] = $v1;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>Last : " . end($newarray1);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing `array_filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Use "isset()" to see if an element is "empty".

Use "count()" to determine the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can this operation with a function as well:

```
<?php
    function getLastElement($data=array())
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
        {
            if($i==count($data)-1)
            {
                $end = $data[$i];
            }
        }
        return $end;
    }
?>
```